# script/runner in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, daemon

I have 2 jobs I would like to run and they are dependant on Models in my rails application.
I added the ruby files in a separate folder called Jobs, that I have appended to the rail project.

Whenever I try to run them via ruby command I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant Feedback (NameError).

Feedback here is a model I'm using in my rails app.

My questions: because the jobs I'm using are actually compatible with the script/runner command of rails 2, is there an alternative with Rails 3? If not how can I write ruby programs that depend on models I have in a rails app without getting the error I mentioned above.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `rails runner`

```
$ rails -h
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
...
runner       Run a piece of code in the application environment

All commands can be run with -h for more information.
```

Answer (score 3):

The "Rails 3 way" to do this is with Rake using the `:environment` prerequisite, which loads the Rails environment. Like so:

```
task :name => :environment do |t|
  # actions
end
```

In the block you can load and execute your jobs.

If you haven't written Rake scripts before, [here's a good tutorial](http://jasonseifer.com/2010/04/06/rake-tutorial). It's quite easy.