# Rails script error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

i wrote a script to fill a database using values from an excel page. In the script I'm getting the error

```
uninitialized constant Profile (NameError)
```

Profile is the name of a model i have. Rails looks it is not recognizing my model in the script. How can fix this.

Comment: You need to post some code. Your script and your Profile model would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Rails doesn't get properly initialized.

Can you post the script, and explain how you run / start it?

Which version of Rails do you use?

If you have a rails application and you want to run a task as a script, there are two ways to do it:

1) via script runner

2) via rake

If you use rake, you have to tell it to initialize your Rails application properly. 
   The rake tasks need to be under `./lib/tasks`

Check out these Posts, which explain how to do it:

[I have a Rails task: should I use script/runner or rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591503/rails-task-script-runner-or-rake)

[script/runner in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241425/script-runner-in-rails-3)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: nope, its spelled fine. Is there some sort of statement i need to call from profile in my script

Comment: I mean like in scripts/pull_profile.rb do i need a line like use Profile

Comment: what do you mean by script? do you have a Rails application?